# What should I care about when buying a new battery pack for a laptop?

Tags: battery

I need to buy a new battery. The model of the battery is Li-Ion Battery Pack A41-K53. Rating = 14.4v 2600mAh, 37Wh. I searched and found the same model, but voltage and mAh is different. The voltage of the new battery I looked is 10.8 and mAh is 4400. If I bought that battery, would I have a problem? What are other things I should care about?

Comment: "If I bought that battery, would I have a problem?" Yes. It won't work and may even go boom.

Answer (score 1):

If it has the same model but not the same voltage, it's not good enough.

Requirements to look for:

- It has to fit in the battery slot. So check the dimensions and the connector.
- It has to be the exact same voltage. While it's technically possible at times to use a differing voltage, you really only want to do this when you're sure what you're doing and can tackle the risk. Considering the only modes of failure with Li-ion batteries (all modern laptop batteries) are flames, smoke and explosions, you really don't want to do that.

Amperage-hours (in mAh) is basically the storage capacity. More mAh is like having a bigger gas tank in your car: when completely filled up it takes longer before you have to recharge. So a 2600 mAh is good, but a 4400 mAh has more capacity. Keep in mind that the *useful* capacity is 0 if it doesn't fit and has the wrong voltage, so those requirements are *much* more important than the amperage-hour rating.

Answer (score 0):

On some batteries you can go up to 10% +, but no -. But this battery is probably not going to work OK.Yor laptop needs 14.4 and you wanr 10.8 as far as I see. So you MBO,processor, RAM and everythin else will have 3.6v in lack of.

You need to put battery with the same voltage(up to +10% is OK on most of new batteries) and capacity is not important. And size must be the same. I mean you can not put bigger battery in smaller slot. And it need ti be cerificated by laptop manufacter or you can lost warratny and put yourself in risk.

Comment: Warranty is not the only problem. Using a battery which communicates differently than the laptop will mean they won't communicate at all. Modern Li-ion batteries and their charging systems are quite complicated nowadays, it's not as easy as with old-fashioned lead-acid ones.